# IndexError: list index out of range: NumPy python

Tags: python, numpy, index

estoy haciendo un programa que me permita calcular la big m en el método simplex en python pero tengo un error en los indices y nose como arreglarlos.

[image: code1]

[image: code2]

[image: code3]

```
def obtener_solucion (tabla, variables): 

    solucion = np.zeros(len(variables))

    indices_variables = np.where(tabla[1:,:-1] 1)[1]

    for i, indice in enumerate (indices_variables):

        solucion1[indice] = tabla [i + 1, -1]

    return solucion 

'''


 en la imagen de du3 es donde tengo el error intente hacer el recorrido de otra forma y nada la verdad no creo que mas pueda ser nose como hacer que dinámicamente me tome los valores de la tabla
```

Comment: El código que añades no es válido en Python. Por favor edita tu pregunta proveyendo un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Debes añadir tambien el traceback de tu error junto con tu codigo

Comment: Hola Mairon, tanto el código como los mensajes de error, deben estar como texto, no en imágenes, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y la adaptes a los requerimientos del sitio, de esa forma lograrás que sea mejor recibida y evitarás recibir votos negativos.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que el error se debe a que en `tabla [i + 1, -1]` se le agregar el `+1` y cuando llega al final va un valor mas alla del largo total (osease, si en unas lista de 10 valores, va a terminar iterando en el valor 11, pero como no existe, causa error)